# How accurate is reflectance confocal microscopy (RCM) to predict whether a basal cell carcinoma (BCC) is infiltrative or superficial?

Tags: dermatology, diagnostics, medical-imaging, basal-cell-carcinoma

Reflectance confocal microscopy (RCM) is a noninvasive imaging technique that has been used to diagnose basal cell carcinoma (BCC). How accurate is RCM to predict whether a BCC is infiltrative or superficial?

The 2006 study {2} was inconclusive:

> Limitations: The pigmented BCCs imaged in this study were predominantly nodular; a different set or additional criteria may be necessary for detection of infiltrative and metatypical BCCs.

The 2016 study {1} focused on superficial basal cell carcinoma (sBCC) but only looked at 3 cases.

Motivations:

1. Understanding if RCM is a decent replacement for a [biopsy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/25050/43) to diagnose BCC.
2. [Superficial BCCs can be treated quite well with Imiquimod 5% cream (US brand: Aldara)](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/25022/43) but [Imiquimod not doesn't work as well on infiltrative BCCs](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/25008/43), which typically requires surgery (Mohs if cosmesis is important or old-fashioned excision).

---

References:

- {1} Ghita, Mihaela A., Constantin Caruntu, Adrian E. Rosca, Harillaq Kaleshi, Ana Caruntu, Liliana Moraru, Anca Oana Docea et al. "[Reflectance confocal microscopy and dermoscopy for in vivo, non-invasive skin imaging of superficial basal cell carcinoma](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4840988/)." Oncology letters 11, no. 5 (2016): 3019-3024. [DOI](https://dx.doi.org/10.3892%2Fol.2016.4354) ;
- {2} Agero, Anna Liza Chan, Klaus J. Busam, Cristiane Benvenuto-Andrade, Alon Scope, Melissa Gill, Ashfaq A. Marghoob, Salvador González, and Allan C. Halpern. "[Reflectance confocal microscopy of pigmented basal cell carcinoma](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaad.2005.11.1096)." Journal of the American Academy of Dermatology 54, no. 4 (2006): 638-643.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer may be currently unknown, the best [review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6492459/) I found, which was most recent, shows the real need for larger blinded trials.  Seems reasonable but not confirmed or validated at this point.  Looking at FDA test submissions, that seems to be the trend there as well.